# didSelectItemAt indexPath: is not working in UICollectionview for some reason

Tags: swift, uicollectionview

Here is my code for the collectionView. All is working perfect except when I click on an item in the collectionView the "didSelectItemAt" function does not work (print statement is not executed). I don't expect you to know why but can you please tell me what I could possibly check to get the select function going.

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "collectionViewCell", for: indexPath) as! CollectionViewCell
    let key = imageArray[indexPath.row]
    cell.displayContent(image: key)  ///function in CollectionViewCell
    return cell
}


func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    print("in here\(indexPath.row)")
}
```

Comment: Did you set the collection view's delegate? Is it possible your cell has views that are stealing the touch event?

Comment: Is the selection enabled, and user interaction enabled, and no view inside the cell is capturing your gestures  (like a button for example) ??

Comment: it was the missing delegate, thanks! please set as answer

Comment: I think you should also have to use indexPath.item

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had a similar problem and realized I was missing the following:

```
self.collectionView.delegate = self
```

I build my UI programmatically so hopefully this helps you as well.